# Norm of a $(1, 1)$ form on a Kähler manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Given a Kähler manifold $(M, g)$ what is the convention for defining the inner product on two $(1,1)$ forms $\alpha = \sqrt{-1}\alpha_{i \bar k} dz_{i} \wedge d \bar{z}_{k}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{-1}\beta_{i \bar k} dz_{i} \wedge d \bar{z}_{k}$. It is my impression that $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle_{g} = g^{i \bar \delta} g^{\gamma \bar j}\alpha_{i \bar j} \beta_{\gamma \bar \delta}$. However this seems to be the definition on tensor products rather than wedge products.

Comment: Sorry about that and I have improved the notation,

Comment: If by inner product you mean the hermitian inner product, then don't forget that one of the arguments (for mathematicians, the second argument, for physicists, the first) gets complex conjugated.